# JavaScript objects array filter by minimum value of an attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, ecmascript-6

I need to filter this object array by minimum value of 'rest' attribute. This is an one way to do it. Is there any other ways ?

'data' variable is a result of chained function. Is there any other way to do this without calling 'data' variable again inside  Math.min() function.

```js
let data = 
[ { size: 5, qty: 2, rest: 0 },
  { size: 2, qty: 5, rest: 0 },
  { size: 1, qty: 10, rest: 0 },
  { size: 3, qty: 3, rest: 1 },
  { size: 4, qty: 2, rest: 2 } ]

let result = data.filter(e=> e.rest === Math.min(...data.map(f=>f.rest) ) );
console.log(result);

// result is
//[ { size: 5, qty: 2, rest: 0 },
//  { size: 2, qty: 5, rest: 0 },
//  { size: 1, qty: 10, rest: 0 }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imo. the simplest/best solution is the one @CertainPerformance gave you.

Just wanted to add another solution with linear runtime *(that truly iterates only once over the Array)*

```js
let data = [
  { size: 5, qty: 2, rest: 0 },
  { size: 2, qty: 5, rest: 0 },
  { size: 1, qty: 10, rest: 0 },
  { size: 3, qty: 3, rest: 1 },
  { size: 4, qty: 2, rest: 2 } 
];

let result = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  let minRest = result.length? result[0].rest: item.rest;

  if (item.rest < minRest) {
    minRest = item.rest;
    result.length = 0;
  }

  if (item.rest === minRest) {
    result.push(item);
  }

  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

@mathieux51 got me another idea how you can do this inside a method chain, but the readability/clarity/intention is not as good as with the other approaches:

```js
let data = [
  { size: 5, qty: 2, rest: 0 },
  { size: 2, qty: 5, rest: 0 },
  { size: 1, qty: 10, rest: 0 },
  { size: 3, qty: 3, rest: 1 },
  { size: 4, qty: 2, rest: 2 } 
];

let result = data.sort((a, b) => a.rest - b.rest)
                 .filter((item, index, array) => item.rest === array[0].rest);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Last one is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorting has `O(N log N)` complexity though

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is to pull the min function out of the filter like this:

```
let min = Math.min(...data.map(item => item.rest))
```

This is much more efficient as we are no longer loop over the data to find the min for every iteration of the filter.

We now have n * 2 passes instead of n^2 passes. (n is the size of your data set, 5 in this case)

Full example below:

```js
let data = [ 
  { size: 5, qty: 2, rest: 0 },
  { size: 2, qty: 5, rest: 0 },
  { size: 1, qty: 10, rest: 0 },
  { size: 3, qty: 3, rest: 1 },
  { size: 4, qty: 2, rest: 2 } 
]

let min = Math.min(...data.map(item => item.rest))
let result = data.filter(item => item.rest === min)
console.log(result)
```

Hope this helps!

Lloyd

Comment: Thank you.yeah I missed that issue.  Isn't there any other way to do this with method chaining ?

Comment: you will always have to compare the rest values to a minimum variable or pre defined threshold, your initial post is an example of Method chaining.

Comment: Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 4):

`data.map` inside of `data.filter` is `O(N^2)`; for an `O(N)` solution, iterate through `data` ahead of time to calculate the minimum, then `filter` by that minimum:

```js
let data = 
[ { size: 5, qty: 2, rest: 0 },
  { size: 2, qty: 5, rest: 0 },
  { size: 1, qty: 10, rest: 0 },
  { size: 3, qty: 3, rest: 1 },
  { size: 4, qty: 2, rest: 2 } ];
const minRest = Math.min(...data.map(({ rest }) => rest));

let result = data.filter(({ rest }) => rest === minRest);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. yet this isn't what I'm looking for. is there any other way without declaring a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately no, you'll *have* to declare or use another variable if you want `O(N)` performance. (if you don't want to expose it to the outer scope, feel free to put it into an IIFE)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to *sort* the list. I would do it as following:

```
const result = data.sort((a, b) => a.rest - b.rest)
```

Comment: sort and filter by minimum `rest` value.

Comment: Just sorting should also work. Get first or last item which would be min and max

Answer (score 0):

**Get Min or Max**
Since no one mentioned this method I will update it here.

```
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
return a.rest - b.rest
})

var min = myArray[0],
max = myArray[myArray.length - 1]
```

It has good readability/clarity/intentions.