# How can I show only 1 record which has a least score among all?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I wanted to show only 1 record among the DL list which has a minimum score from all the DLs. Currently it's displaying all the records.

In the example on stackblitz you can see for the first record DL scores are : 54, 20 and updated.

I want Instead of showing all 3 records I wanted to display only 1 record which has least score i.e. 20.

Please suggest.

Markup

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let assignee of user.assigned_to">
{{assignee.dl}} {{assignee.co_score}}
</li>
</ul>
```

Live
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1tsz1r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find working example here in this [stackbliz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7nnnby?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffilter-dl.pipe.ts)

I have created one pipe to filter out data...

**custom-pipe is**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "filterDL"
})

export class FilterDLPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        console.log("filter pipe ", value);
        let filter = value.filter(item => Number(item.co_score));
        let leastScrore = Math.min(...filter.map(item => item.co_score));
        let findIndex = filter.filter(item => item.co_score === leastScrore);
        console.log("findex", findIndex);
        console.log(leastScrore);
      return findIndex;
    }
}
```

then apply this pipe to your DL array to filter out array.

```
<ul>
     <li *ngFor="let assignee of user.assigned_to | filterDL">
                {{assignee.dl}} {{assignee.co_score}}
     </li>
</ul>
```

and you will get your desired minimum score outpur in DL.

Comment: you are a life saver!

Comment: there is a small issue if you will click on any record other than first and click on previous n next it's happening from the first record only, not taking that specific record index. can you please look into that?

Comment: I believe it's the conflict with pagination control, let me update the stackblitz and show you

Comment: https://angular-ivy-hkrfyu.stackblitz.io/ please refer to this and see any record from page 2. in the details see how previous n next behaving differently.

Comment: thats another issue, see this link and check here its working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7nnnby?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffilter-dl.pipe.ts

Comment: the one shared by you previously working perfectly but along with pagination its not. need your help in that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65698330/my-next-and-previous-control-not-able-to-take-the-correct-index-when-paginating

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try it to find the lowest score in one step and return the index, and then grab the element at that index from the assigned_to array in the next step.
If you want to go deeper, you could look at the `filter` and `find` methods on `Array`

Comment: can you please update the stackblitz as i am new into this will end up creating more issues. appreciate your help

Comment: Would this post help you figure it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097817/javascript-objects-array-filter-by-minimum-value-of-an-attribute