# How to add next and previous control in the record detail view?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, navigationcontroller

If you will click on any of the record row you will see the details of the record.

I wanted to add next and previous button on the details of next/previous row without click on top row. So that user don't have to click again back to top row to view details. They can simply use next / previous control to see next and previous record details.

I was trying this but didn't help.

```
<div *ngIf="isView" class="view-details">
    <button (click)="onPrev()">Prev</button>
<button (click)="onNext()">Next</button>
```

component.ts

```
current = 0;
  prev = -1;

  onPrev() {
    this.prev = this.allUser.current--;
    alert("Prev" + this.prev);
  }
  onNext() {
    this.prev = this.allUser.current++;
    alert("Next" + this.prev);
  }
```

Please help me with the solution.

You can view the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1tsz1r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: from your stackbliz its not clear what is your problem. Can you explain it more?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda if you will click on any of the record, you will see details of it with 2 links previous n next. I want on click of it to see previous n next record details instead of every time I click on top to see details, I want a direct navigation to reduce clicks n directly see details of next or previous record.

Comment: Please add a minimum viable question with code example and try to explain the problem you are facing. Also update the link to stackblitz.

Comment: @iepur1lla i did update the question will more details. if you can look into it and suggest me solution that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find example here in this [StackBliz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7nnnby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Inside you table tr click I have added new method parameter like below..

```
<tr class="record-row" (click)="viewUser(user, i, filteredUsers)"
                *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers;let i = index">
```

and Inside your component viewUser() method is...

```
viewUser(user: any, index, filterData) {
  this.isView = true;
  console.log(user, index, filterData);
  this.userObj = user;
  this.currentIndex = index;
  this.allUserTableData = filterData;
}
```

In above i have added two new class-variable `currentIndex` and `allUserTableData`. based on this two data variable next and previous traversal is looks like below code...

**now.. next traversal code is**

```
nextRecord() {
   let next = (this.currentIndex += 1);
   if (next > this.allUserTableData.length - 1) {
     this.currentIndex = 5;
     return;
   }
   let nextRecord = this.allUserTableData[next];
    this.userObj = nextRecord;
    console.log(nextRecord, next);
 }
```

**previouse traversal code is**

```
previousRecord() {
  let next = (this.currentIndex -= 1);
  if (next < 0) {
    this.currentIndex = 0;
    return;
  }
  let nextRecord = this.allUserTableData[next];
  this.userObj = nextRecord;
  console.log(nextRecord, next);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Can I ask for your help for 1 last issue please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678821/how-can-i-show-only-1-record-which-has-a-least-score-among-all

Comment: I have given answer to that question to!!