# Why my next and previous control not able to take the correct index when paginating? What changes do I need to make?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, navigation

In my code when you click on any of the record you will see the details. In the details there are 2 links (previous, next) to navigate to previous n next record. On the first page it is working fine. But when I navigate to next page from pagination and click on previous n next it still taking the first page row index and previous n next is happening from the row instead of select row.

You can view here: https://angular-ivy-hkrfyu.stackblitz.io/

```
    nextRecord() {
    let next = (this.currentIndex += 1);
    if (next > this.allUserTableData.length - 1) {
      this.currentIndex = 1;
      return;
    }
    let nextRecord = this.allUserTableData[next];
    this.userObj = nextRecord;
    console.log(nextRecord, next);
  }
  previousRecord() {
    let next = (this.currentIndex -= 1);
    if (next < 0) {
      this.currentIndex = 0;
      return;
    }
    let nextRecord = this.allUserTableData[next];
    this.userObj = nextRecord;
    console.log(nextRecord, next);
  }

<button (click)="previousRecord()">Previous</button> | <button (click)="nextRecord()">Next</button>
```

Comment: give me stackbliz link of yours where new pagination control is there.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda you can view here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hkrfyu

Comment: @gaurangdhorda were you able to view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find working example here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y6ktlp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I have added new parameter inside `viewuser()`

```
<tr class="record-row" (click)="viewUser(user, i, filteredUsers, 5, page)"
```

**and inside viewUser()**

```
viewUser(user: any, index, filterData, itemsPerPage, currentPage) {
  console.log(itemsPerPage, currentPage);
  let currentPageIndex = currentPage;
  let recordPerPageToShow = itemsPerPage;

  let findCurrentRecordToSkip = (currentPageIndex - 1) * recordPerPageToShow;
  let countIndex = findCurrentRecordToSkip + recordPerPageToShow;

  console.log(
  "filter-pagination",
  filterData.slice(findCurrentRecordToSkip, countIndex)
  );

 this.isView = true;
 console.log(user, index, filterData);
 this.userObj = user;
 this.currentIndex = index;
 this.allUserTableData = filterData.slice(
  findCurrentRecordToSkip,
  countIndex
 );
}
```

Comment: can you please check it again it's not working :(

Comment: when go to next page n click on any record n do previous next from that records it's not happening, also from 1st page last record click on next it's not going...

Comment: in my case, when you click `2`, and then you click on record then it will only show you 3 records to traverse only.

Comment: you must have to click on record after you changed pagination index, in order to traverse to only to that of records only

Comment: correct but on those records previous next link control are not working. if you click on previous n next nothing will happen. or same in the first page last record "G Male" when you click on details n next it's should show "Female Record" but not happening. Did you get what I am trying to show you?

Comment: previous n next not able to move along with the pagination. so, right now its' doing only on those record in pagination view... 1-5 n 6-8 but when click on 6 not going on 5.. or 5 to 6

Comment: then very first solution is already working for you. Then Why pagination controls here? keep those two things different . I think You should not mix both controls .

Comment: the only reason in real data I have almost 3000 records so, that's why pagination is required n prev / next would be easy to navigate instead of click on every record to see the details

Comment: yes, keep next , previous traversal only to those page numbers only. for next page, have to change pagination manually. then next, previous, records only for current page index.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. I am just wanted to provide better seamless UI..

Comment: thats correct, But technically its not feasible to change page index from next, previous traversal, keep those both seperate.. thats right way to do your things

Comment: thanks let me speak to client on this n explain the technical challenge.  in the meantime one last favor can you help me with this one? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-87hi8i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html if you will see sort is working on first name n last name but it's not working on dl n dl score. can you please help me with this? n thanks again for your help.

Comment: I can atleast add disable class on previous when you r on first record n disable on next on last record for some better view

Comment: yes!! You can do this or display alert message what to do next

Comment: sure. thanks. can you see this one please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700356/why-sorting-is-not-working-on-some-of-the-columns

Comment: hi!! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y6ktlp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts check this link I have updated next, previous, traversal with pagination index will change accordingly too!! is this working fine or not?

Comment: perfect ! thanks a ton. can you tell me one thing how do i add a row highlight effect which will give the idea of which row is selected currently?

Comment: better than expected. only last thing how do i add background-color/class to row which selected to give better understanding.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y6ktlp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts checkout highlight part too!!

Comment: just a small change it should apply on click, initial page load its also highlighted the first row.

Comment: where did you make the change as ngclass looks same to me.. :D

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y6ktlp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts check this

Comment: thanks mate. if i will ask you something else are you going to kil me? :D

Comment: I wanted to sort the view based on DL score so, least dl score row record should come on top followed by next DL score. ({assignee.co_score})

Comment: explain more each table raw has `assigned_to`  ? then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227282/discussion-between-kunal-vijan-and-gaurangdhorda).

Comment: it's throwing me error saying "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
"

Comment: From where and which line produce this error.. you can put if condition to check variable is not undefined.. then you start filter

Comment: `let filterList = list.filter(filterUser);`

Comment: it's not rendering anything on page as well because of this...

Comment: Put that line inside if conditions like `if(list){  ... }`

Comment: not helping. is there is anyway I can show you my local code?

Comment: Show me `console.log(list)`

Comment: sorting is working with couple of error in console. `core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at TableFilterPipe.transform (table-filter.pipe.ts:43)
    at pureFunction2Internal (core.js:24590)
    at Module.ɵɵpipeBind2 (core.js:24762)
    at AppComponent_Template (app.component.html:144)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7457)
    at refreshView (core.js:7326)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7132)
    at refreshView (core.js:7376)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:7440)`

Comment: `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Set]'. Current value: '[object Set]'.
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.js:2216)
    at bindingUpdated (core.js:13973)
    at Module.ɵɵproperty (core.js:14717)
    at AppComponent_Template (app.component.html:104)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7457)
    at refreshView (core.js:7326)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7132)
    at refreshView (core.js:7376)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:7440)`

Comment: console.log(list) showing VM901:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: list is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: let me check it out! meanwhile please come to discussion chat..